# MatplotlibDeprecationWarning when adding background color to subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to create a box plot from a data set and then change background color for each of the subplots:

```
url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jbrownlee/Datasets/master/iris.csv"
column_names = ['sepal-length', 'sepal-width', 'petal-length', 'petal-width', 'class']
data_set = read_csv(url, names=column_names)


data_set.plot(kind="box", subplots=True, color="yellow", layout=(2, 2), sharex=False, sharey=False)

pyplot.subplot(221).set_facecolor("red")
pyplot.subplot(222).set_facecolor("purple")
pyplot.subplot(223).set_facecolor("green")
pyplot.subplot(224).set_facecolor("blue")

pyplot.show()
```

I do get the colored subplots, however, I keep getting the warning message:

```
MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: Adding an axes using the same arguments as a previous axes currently reuses the earlier instance.  In a future version, a new instance will always be created and returned.  Meanwhile, this warning can be suppressed, and the future behavior ensured, by passing a unique label to each axes instance.
```

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be an ongoing issue in Matplotlib which hasn't been resolved as of today. From reading the thread here [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/12513), there doesn't seem to be an imminent risk of Deprecation.

However, if you want this message to go away, you can try what this user tried [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52989341/12149851). The user here replaced `fig.subplot()` with `fig.add_subplot()`